# Cómo puedo definir la variable de "Notice: Undefined variable: archi"

Tags: php

No sé cómo resolver el problema sobre el `Notice` definiendo correctamente la variable `$archi` para que me pueda listar correctamente el contenido del directorio.

Les agradezco sinceramente cualquier tipo de ayuda o explicación, este es el código:

```
<?php
// Lista los temas alfabeticamente
$ruta = "archivos/songs/";
$filehandle = opendir($ruta);
while (false !== ($file = readdir($filehandle))) {
   if ($file != "." && $file != ".." && substr($file,-4)==".mp3") {
        $arch=$file;
        $archi=$arch.'*'.$archi;
      }
}    
closedir($filehandle);

// Inicio paginación 
$archivosfile = explode ("*", $archi);
sort($archivosfile);
$currentpage = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; // Página donde se encuentra 
$total=(count($archivosfile)-1); 
$maxRows = 10;  // Cantidad máxima de archivos a mostrar por página 
$pageNum = 0; 

if (isset($_GET['pag'])) { 
  $pageNum = intval($_GET['pag']); 
} 
$startRow = $pageNum * $maxRows; 
if (isset($_GET['pag'])) { 
  $pageNum = intval($_GET['pag']); 
}
$startRow = $pageNum * $maxRows;
$totalRows = $total; 
$totalPages = ceil($totalRows/$maxRows)-1;
$archivos = array_slice($archivosfile, $startRow, $maxRows);
?>
```

Comment: Muestra la porción de codigo que esta dando el error.

Comment: Deberías indicar en qué línea recibes el error

Comment: En cuestión es en la línea 8 correspondiente a $archi=$arch.'*'.$archi;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La variable `$archi` la estás creando en un ámbito e intentando acceder a ella desde otro diferente, para tenerla disponible fuera del if y del bucle tienes que crearla fuera, para ello:

```
<?php
// Lista los temas alfabeticamente
$ruta = "archivos/songs/";
$archi = "";
$filehandle = opendir($ruta); 
    while (false !== ($file = readdir($filehandle))) {
    if ($file != "." && $file != ".." && substr($file,-4)==".mp3") {
        $arch=$file;
        $archi=$arch.'*'.$archi;
    }
}
closedir($filehandle);
$archivosfile = explode ("*", $archi);
...
```

Comment: Perfecto!!! gracias por la explicación me has enseñado!