# Problema al listar archivos de un directorio, el primer resultado lo muestra en blanco

Tags: php

No sé el motivo de por qué al listar los archivos del directorio, el primer resultado siempre lo imprime en blanco, tal como se muestra en la imagen adjunta.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El código que estoy usando es:

```
<?php
// Lista los temas alfabeticamente
$ruta = "archivos/songs/";
$archi = "";
$filehandle = opendir($ruta);
while (false !== ($file = readdir($filehandle))) {
if ($file != "." && $file != ".." && substr($file,-4)==".mp3") {     
    $arch=$file;
    $archi=$arch.'*'.$archi;  
  }
}
closedir($filehandle);

// Inicio paginación 
$archivosfile = explode ("*", $archi);
sort($archivosfile);
$currentpage = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; // Página donde se encuentra 
$total=(count($archivosfile)-1); 
$maxRows = 10; // Cantidad máxima de archivos a mostrar por página 
$pageNum = 0; // Página de inicio

if (isset($_GET['pag'])) { 
$pageNum = intval($_GET['pag']); 
} 
$startRow = $pageNum * $maxRows; 

if (isset($_GET['pag'])) { 
$pageNum = intval($_GET['pag']); 
} 
$startRow = $pageNum * $maxRows; 
$totalRows = $total; 
$totalPages = ceil($totalRows/$maxRows)-1; 
$archivos = array_slice($archivosfile, $startRow, $maxRows); 
// Fín paginación    
?>

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div style="float:left;padding:4px;margin-left:1px;">
    <h2>Los <?php echo $total;  ?> temas de la lista</h2>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<?php
foreach ($archivos as $archivo) {
$archivo = preg_replace("#.mp3#", '', $archivo); 
echo '<div class="caja-menu seccion" style="height: 185px">
<img src="archivos/songs/'.$archivo.'.jpg" onerror="imgError(this);" style="float:left;margin:16px" width="125" height="125"> 
<p><p>
<a href=""><span style="font-size:180%">'.$archivo.'</span></a>
<br>
<a class="btn btn-default" role="button" target="_self" href="indexSongsPlayer.php?id=archivos/songs/'.$archivo.'.mp3">
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-headphones"></span>&nbsp;&nbsp;Escuchar</a>';
echo '</div>';
}
?>
```

Comment: Hola @Jaime. Copié el código que tenías en tu [pregunta anterior](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/133326/127) ... De esta forma, no es necesario tener que ir a otra publicación para ver qué tenés... Por favor revisalo para ver si es así como está actualmente

Comment: Hola y gracias, faltaba una parte del código para completarlo

Answer (score 4, accepted):

El problema se debe a que por cada elemento siempre estas agregando un `*`.

Supongamos que tienes los siguientes archivos: `Abba1` y `Abba2`.
Al momento de agregar el nombre del archivo a la variable `$archi`, haces esto: `$archi=$arch.'*'.$archi;`, es decir que:

```
// En la primer vuelta
$archi = 'Aba1*';
// En la segunda vuelta
$archi = 'Aba2*Aba1*';
```

Si prestas atención, tienes 2 `*`, luego al hacer `$archivosfile = explode ("*", $archi);`, te dará como resultado un `Array` con 3 elementos y el último estará vació. Por último al hacer `sort($archivosfile);` dicho elemento quedará primero en el arreglo.

### Soluciones:

#### Opción 1

Podrías usar [substr](http://php.net/manual/es/function.substr.php) para remover el último `*` del `String`

```
//... código anterior
$archi = substr($archi, 0, -1);
$archivosfile = explode ("*", $archi);
```

#### Opción 2

Podrías definir directamente un `Array` y agregar las pistas en este.

```
$ruta = "archivos/songs/";
$archivosfile = []; // Eliminamos la variable `$archi`
$filehandle = opendir($ruta);
while (false !== ($file = readdir($filehandle))) {
if ($file != "." && $file != ".." && substr($file,-4)==".mp3") {     
    $archivosfile[]=$file; // Agregamos las pistas al arreglo
  }
}
closedir($filehandle);

// Inicio paginación 
sort($archivosfile); // Ordenamos el arreglo
//... resto del código
```

Comment: Marcos, es muy correcto, además tu explicación me queda clarisima. Gracias por la ayuda!!!. Me quedo con la opción 2 es más robusta!